# with the top end of the table just inside the house

Tags: grammar, meaning

Farmers always gave a special supper to the sheep shearers when they had finished their work.
This year Bathsheba had ordered her maids to put a long table in the garden, ***with*** the top end of the table just inside the house.
Far from the madding crowd , By Thomas Hardy

What kind of structure is this? (with part)

and what is the meaning of the sentence?(with .......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table was in the garden. Presumably the house had a wide enough door or window opening onto the garden for the table to pass through it, so that 'the top of the table' (the end where the principal guests sat) could be inside the house.

Similar uses of *with*:

The chair was placed with its feet on the mat. She lay with her head on a pillow.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is that the long table protrudes through an opening in the house, either a door or a big window, so that part of the table is inside the house (the end of the table called the top), and part is outside.

The relevant meaning of "with" is here:

[Merriam-Webster "with" 7b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with)

7b. used as a function word to indicate an attendant fact or circumstance *stood there with his hat on*